# Singly linked list with priority keys, keys don't get printed

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue, singly-linked-list

Why would this be? As well as they keys not being printed, the elements are being printed in the wrong order.

```
    pq.enqueue(1,"Some");
    pq.enqueue(2,"Words");
    pq.enqueue(3,"Strange");
    pq.enqueue(4,"Very");
    System.out.println(pq.size());
    pq.dequeue();
    pq.printPQueue();
    System.out.println("Is the list empty? " +pq.isEmpty());
```

The output for this is:

```
4
Key = 0 Element= Strange
Key = 0 Element= Words
Key = 0 Element= Some
Is the list empty? false
```

There are two issues I can see, the keys remain 0 and the elements are printed in the wrong order.

Edit:

Interface class, to define the methods:

```
public interface PQInterface {
    public void enqueue(int key, Object element);
    public Object dequeue();
    public int size();
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public void printPQueue();
}
```

Node class (setters and getters):

```
public class Node {
    private int key;
    private Object element;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int priority, Object e, Node n){
        element = e;
        next = n;
    }

    public int getKey(){
        return key; 
    }

    public void setKey(int val){
        key = val;
    }

    public Node getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n){
        next = n;
    }

public Object getElement(){
    return element;
}

    public void setElement(Object e){
        element = e;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return element.toString();
    }
}
```

Finally, the MyPriorityQueue class which implements the methods defined in the interface.

```
public class MyPriorityQueue implements PQInterface {

private Node head;
private int size;
private Node curr;
private Node prev;

public MyPriorityQueue() {
    head = null;
    size = 0;
    curr = null;
    prev = null;
}

private void setCurrent(int index){
    prev=null;
    curr=head;
    for(int k=1; k<index; k++){
        prev=curr;
        curr=curr.getNext();
    }
}

private int findInsertPosition(int newkey){
    Node aNode=head;
    boolean found;
    int position;
    found=false;
    position=1;
    while(aNode!=null && !found){
        if(aNode.getKey()>newkey){
            aNode=aNode.getNext();
            position=position+1;
        }
        else{
            found=true;
        }
    }
    return position;
}

public void add(int index, int priorkey, Object item){
    if(index==1){
        Node newNode = new Node(priorkey,item,head);
        head=newNode;
    }
    else{
        setCurrent(index);
        Node newNode = new Node(priorkey,item,curr);
        prev.setNext(newNode);
    }
    size=size+1;
}

private void add(int priorkey, Object element){
    Node newNode = new Node(priorkey,element,null);
    if(head==null){
        head=newNode;
    }
    else{
        setCurrent(size);
        curr.setNext(newNode);
    }
    size=size+1;
}

@Override
public void enqueue(int priorkey, Object item) {
    int index;
    index = findInsertPosition(priorkey);
    if (index > size) {
        add(priorkey, item);
    } else {
        add(index, priorkey, item);
    }

}

@Override
public Object dequeue(){
    Node toBeRemoved;
    toBeRemoved = head;
    head = head.getNext();
    size = size-1;
    return toBeRemoved;
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (size == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void printPQueue(){
    Node aNode=head;
    while(aNode!=null){
        System.out.println("Key = "+aNode.getKey()+" Element= "+aNode.getElement());
        aNode=aNode.getNext();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should edit your question to include all relevant code.

Comment: Okay, I've included all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never store the priority in the Node object :

```
public class Node {
    private int key;
    private Object element;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int priority, Object e, Node n){ // priority parameter is not used
        element = e;
        next = n;
    }
    ...
```

That's why key remains 0.

Change it to :

```
public class Node {
    private int key;
    private Object element;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int priority, Object e, Node n){
        element = e;
        next = n;
        key = priority;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Although when I run it, the list is printed backwards still. Keys in order 3,2,1 rather than 1,2,3. Is this normal? (First time working with SLL / p.queues).

Comment: @AdamHorrigan Isn't the idea of this priority queue to put elements with higher priority before elements with lower priority? You get the list in descending priority order.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Node(int priority, Object e, Node n){
    element = e;
    next = n;
}
```

You never set the key in your nodes constructor.

```
public Node(int priority, Object e, Node n){
    element = e;
    next = n;
    this.key = priority;
}
```